# How to add album arts in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using Flute music player plugin to make music player app in Flutter. But I am having a trouble for adding album art.

I wrote:

```
  dynamic getImage(int idx) {
      return _songs[idx].albumArt == null
      ? null
      : new File.fromUri(Uri.parse(_songs[idx].albumArt));
  }
```

And I used Image.file Widget:

```
Container(
    childe: Image.file(getImage(_index))
)
```

And the result is:

```
I/flutter (15576): The following assertion was thrown building HyperMusicHome(dirty, state:
I/flutter (15576): _HyperMusicHomeState#b83f2):
I/flutter (15576): 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 621 pos 14: 'file !=
I/flutter (15576): null': is not true.
I/flutter (15576):
I/flutter (15576): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (15576): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (15576): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (15576):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
```

Comment: I edited and add the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting comes from [this line](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart#L621) in Flutter's `FileImage` class which checks whether what you're passing to `Image.file()` is `null`. It seems like the song you're currently viewing does not have an album art. All you need to do is not show the image when no album art is available.

I don't know what exactly your widget looks like, but you could do something like this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Call `getImage` once to get the image file (which might be `null`)
  final albumArtFile = getImage(_index);

  return Container(
    // Only show the image if `albumArtFile` is not `null`
    child: albumArtFile != null ? Image.file(albumArtFile) : null,
  );
}
```

You could also bundle a placeholder image with your app and show that when no album art is available:

```dart
albumArtFile != null ? Image.file(albumArtFile) : Image.asset('assets/placeholder.png')
```

You can learn more about adding assets to your app [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

Comment: Oh. I selected the file that has no album art image. I tried debugging, and it says 'albumArt: null'. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept my answer (click the ✓).

Comment: I've just added the music which has album art. Other music apps display the album art, but debugger still says 'albumArt: null'. I think It is the problem of plugin. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, it probably is. It seems like the plugin tries to find the album covers in a specific folder instead of looking at images [embedded *within* the audio files themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_embedded_image_extension).